# copy files in one location to another and modify the copied file by placing some data at particular location in tcl?

Tags: tcl

i have to perform following operation..

1. copy file from one location to another
2. search a word in the given file
3. and move the file pointer to beginning of that line
4. place the data in that location which are copied from other file...

3 files are as follows:

```
C:\program Files(X86)\Route\*.tcl 

C:\Sanity_Automation\Route\*.tcl

C:\Script.tcl
```

First i need to copy files from Route folder in Program Files to 
Sanity_Automation\Route*.tcl

Then i need to search "CloseAllOutputFile keyword in

```
C:/Sanity_Automation/Route/SystemTest.tcl
```

once found, move cursor to the beginning of that line where "CloseAllOutputFile " keyword found.

and place data found on script.tcl to that location.

Comment: Why are you writing a script to do this? It's three specific files, why not just use a text editor? I imagine that you're trying to do something slightly more general, but without knowing a little more about your _real_ problem, it's hard to know what to advise.

Comment: That are not 3 specific files. He want to change ALL files in path 1 to add the contents of path 3 and save the result in path 2.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for pointing that out Johannes. It does rather read as though he's only modifying the contents of SystemTest.tcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, that first "file" is actually a pattern. We need to expand that to a list of *real* filenames. We do that with `glob`.

```
# In braces because there are backslashes
set pattern {C:\Program Files(X86)\Route\*.tcl}
# De-fang the backslashes
set pattern [file normalize $pattern]
# Expand
set sourceFilenames [glob $pattern]
```

Then we want to copy them. We could do this with:

```
set target {C:\Sanity_Automation\Route\}
file copy {*}$sourceFilenames [file normalize $target]
```

But really we also want to build up a list of moved files so that we can process them in the next step. So we do this:

```
set target {C:\Sanity_Automation\Route\}
foreach f $sourceFilenames {
    set t [file join $target [file tail $f]]
    file copy $f $t
    lappend targetFilenames $t
}
```

OK, now we're going to do the insertion processing. Let's start by getting the data to insert:

```
set f [open {C:\Script.tcl}]
set insertData [read $f]
close $f
```

Now, we want to go over each of the files, read them in, find where to do the insertion, actually do the insertion if we find the place, and then write the files back out. (You do text edits by read/modify-in-memory/write rather than trying to modify the file directly. Always.)

```
# Iterating over the filenames
foreach t $targetFilenames {

    # Read in
    set f [open $t]
    set contents [read $f]
    close $f

    # Do the search (this is the easiest way!)
    if {[regexp -indices -line {^.*CloseAllOutputFile} $contents where]} {

        # Found it, so do the insert
        set idx [lindex $where 0]
        set before [string range $contents 0 [expr {$idx-1}]]
        set after [string range $contents $idx end]
        set contents $before$insertData$after

        # We did the insert, so write back out
        set f [open $t "w"]
        puts -nonewline $f $contents
        close $f
    }
}
```

Normally, I'd do the modify as part of the copy, but we'll do it your way here.

Comment: Thanks @Donal Fellows . Your explanation is superb. and it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set sourceDir [file join / Files(x86) Route]
set destinationDir [file join / Sanity_Automation Route]

# Read the script to be inserted

set insertFnm [file join / Script.tcl]
set fil [open $insertFnm]
set insertData [read $fil]
close $fil

# Loop around all the Tcl scripts in the source directory

foreach inFnm [glob [file join $sourceDir *.tcl]] {
    # Determine the name of the output file

    set scriptName [file tail $inFnm]
    set outFnm [file join $destinationDir $scriptName]

    # Open source and destination files, for input and output respectively

    set inFil [open $inFnm]
    set outFil [open $outFnm w]

    while {![eof $inFil]} {
    set line [gets $inFil]
    if {[string match *CloseAllOutputFile* $line]} {
        puts $outFil $insertData
        puts $outFil "";         # Ensure there's a newline at the end
                                     # of the insertion
    }
    puts $outFil $line
    }

    # Close input and output files

    close $inFil
    close $outFil
}
```

It seems to work for me.